# View requirements for custom workflow

Tags: 2010, workflow, workflow-activity

we are using SharePoint 2010. We have there some custom Workflows which created my former colleague. Is there any way to view the requirements for each workflow?

I mean to view some requirements which is necessarily to automatically start the workflow?

I have a problem, because for one item in a list started a bad Workflow and I would like to know why.

Answer (score 2):

To view the workflow details you could simply

- Open your site in SharePoint Designer,
- Open the required list and navigate to "Workflow" section.
- After opening the associated workflow you can easily view the workflow properties (including start mode etc) and workflow steps.